# WCF 4 throws an exception when using FormsAuthentication within the containing website

Tags: wcf, cookies, .net-4.0, jsonp

I have a WCF 4 REST WebService within a folder in my ASP.Net MVC 2 project. JSONP is also enabled on the service using the 'crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled' binding option.
The site and service work great. But, I just noticed that if you are signed in to the website (meaning you have a cookie) and then you 'test' an API method by hitting the URL in the browser I get this error:

> Cross domain
>   javascript callback is not supported
>   in authenticated services.

I'm using Forms Authentication within the site. This happens both when running on my local machine and deployed.

Reading on the Asp.net forums made me think there is an config setting that I need to set to make sure authentication is set to anonymous. Has anyone found a way to get around this? Is there a way to tell WCF to ignore the FormAuthentication cookie?

Comment: I tried setting Context.SkipAuthorization = true in the BeginRequest event but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `<authentication mode="None"/>` in web.config inside `<system.web>` to see if this works locally.